# Interpret Dickey Fuller and KPSS tests

Tags: r, time-series, stationarity

I have a time-series with the following profile (electricity generation):

[image]

My series returns the following, when using both Dickey Fuller and KPSS tests:

```
> adf.test(dataset)

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  dataset
Dickey-Fuller = -8.0272, Lag order = 5, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary

Warning message:
In adf.test(dataset) : p-value smaller than printed p-value
> kpss.test(dataset)

    KPSS Test for Level Stationarity

data:  dataset
KPSS Level = 0.69247, Truncation lag parameter = 4, p-value = 0.01423
```

and

```
> ndiffs(dataset)
[1] 1
```

With Dickey-Fuller, shouldn't a p-value < 0.05 indicates the need for first difference? Shouldn't the KPSS with a p-value < 0.05 indicates that the series is stationary?

After that, in order to make this time series stationary, the correct procedure should be:

- Remove the seasonal component from the dataset via subtraction:

  `components <- decompose(dataset)
  dataset_adjusted <- dataset-components$seasonal`

  To this new `dataset_adjusted`, apply `diff(dataset_adjusted, differences=ndiffs(dataset_adjusted))`
- Apply the difference directly to the dataset via:
  `dataset_diff <- diff(dataset, differences=ndiffs(dataset))`
- Apply the difference based on the frequency via:
  `dataset_diff3 <- diff(dataset, lag=frequency(dataset), differences=ndiffs(dataset))`

All three approaches give different results.

Comment: the KPSS and ADF have opposite nulls when it comes to stationary. Because they do, and because of serious power issues with near unit roots it is suggested that you run both. When they disagree one can't really be sure why they do (although I would guess power often comes into play). Just because a test suggests non-stationarity does not mean you should first difference (or that is enough). You might well have to difference twice - although you should start with first differencing.

Comment: @user54285 thanks a lot for your input! However, there's one thing that keeps bothering me. I can't seem to understand if I should apply both first and/or second difference to the original `dataset`, or to `dataset_adjusted` (the one with the seasonal component subtracted). The resulting ACF/PACF are very different.

Comment: I think the advice is you should first difference and see if the data is stationary (the test you mention are one way to do that, others prefer to look at the ACF/PACF or simply plot the data because they have limited faith in tests like the ADF given power issues). I don't know enough to comment on the seasonality issue.